# Why am I receiving Application Insights warning in Asp.NET Core after upgrading to .Net 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I update my.NET Core Version from the previous version to .NET Core Version 6.0 in visual studio 2022 & update the required packages for my project. But in Program.cs I got the below warning.

> Warning:'ApplicationInsightsWebHostBuilderExtensions.UseApplicationInsights(IWebHostBuilder)'
> is obsolete: 'This method is deprecated in favor of
> AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry() extension method on
> IServiceCollection.'Need to resolve these for .NET Core Version 6.0 in
> visual studio 2022.

**Program.cs**

```
 using System.IO;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
 namespace Demo.API
 {
 public class Program
     {
 public static void Main(string[] args)
         {
 var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                 .UseKestrel()
                 .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                 .UseIISIntegration()
                 .UseStartup<Startup()
                 .UseApplicationInsights()
                 .Build();
 
 host.Run();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried applying what the warning suggests?

Comment: So, it tells you how something changed and by your own post you do not consider doing it but instead ask other people? The warning is pretty clear. Also, it is a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I update my.NET Core Version from the previous version to .NET Core
> Version 6.0 in visual studio 2022 & update the required packages for
> my project. But in Program.cs I got the below warning.

Well, based on your compiler warning message, there might be two major issues within your Upgraded  .NET 6 application.

**Correct Version:**

First of all, for .NET 6 or later version, your [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore) version should be `2.21.0` which you can update from nuget library. You can have a look at the following screenshot:

[image]

**Program.cs Configuration:**

Another important point is that, your program.cs file configuration, that is,  in .NET 6 or later version, program.cs configuration should be:

```
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

But in .NET 5 or earlier it was like below:

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

[image]

So, either of the above issues may ended up with the warning you are getting now.

**Note:** Please refer to the following official document for details implementation and for latest nuget package:

1. [.NET 6 configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcorenew%2Cnetcore6#enable-application-insights-server-side-telemetry-no-visual-studio)
2. Application Insights Updated version [2.21.0 Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore)

Answer (score 4):

That warning message tells you the issue.

In this case; in this new version `.UseApplicationInsights()` has been deprecated and instead `.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry()` should be used.

[Application Insights for ASP.NET (.Net core 6.0)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcorenew%2Cnetcore6)